# Generating Variable Name Dynamically In Python 3

Tags: python

I'm porting some Python 2 code to Python 3

I know this code snippet is bad practice, but I am looking for a way replace the exec() calls.  I basically get "None" back, as predicted by the migration documents.   I tried eval() but I get syntax error messages.

What are the alternatives dynamically generating variable names?

```
value = "test"
for field in ['overviewSynopsis', 'callsToAction_productLevel']:
    exec(field +'_value = ""')
    exec(field +'_value = value')
    print(exec(field + "_value"))
```

Comment: Is there any reason you won't use a dictionary?

Comment: What do you expect to get back? Assignment statements aren't expressions, they don't evaluate to a value. Don't do this to begin with, use a *container* like a dict or a list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `exec` was changed from a statement to an expression.  obviously they want it to bind a name, like it used to in py2.

Comment: It is very difficult to do correctly.  See [How to convert this Python 2.7 code to Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57595351/674039) for example.  Better to refactor the code to use dictionaries instead.

Comment: @wim sure, exec is a function now that always returns `None`, my point is *that assignment statements aren't expressions*, so what would they expect `exec` to return here anyway?

Comment: For that 3rd exec, I assume they probably meant `eval`.

Comment: It sounds like they want `exec` to return whatever is inside it. What I think OP wants is `eval`. However, both should be avoided and OP should use a dictionary instead

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary instead. You can map a key name to a value.

Comment: Duh.  My apologies for not thinking  that.  Thanks for the good idea.