# How to update dictionary values present within local symbol table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope, local-variables

I have written the below program wherein I am trying to modify the `dictionary values` present in `local symbol table`:

```
def modify_locals():
    str = True
    print(locals())
    locals()['str'] = False
    print(locals())

modify_locals()
```

Output:

```
{'str': True}
{'str': True}
```

Please let me know why `locals()['str'] = False` is not updating the `local symbol table`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals `The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600997/python-locals-update-not-working

Comment: first of all don't name a variable on a class name

Comment: Put simply, "here be dragons".  Don't do this.  Really.

Answer (score 0):

`globals()` returns an actual reference to the dictionary that contains the global namespace.

`locals()`, on the other hand, returns a dictionary that is a current copy of the local namespace, not a reference to it. So you can’t modify objects in the actual local namespace using the return value from `locals()`.

This is fully explained in this article: https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/#the-locals-function