# Use String as variable name inside __init__ method

Tags: python, string, exec, init, local-variables

I want to use strings as variable names inside a **init** method of a function, however it does not seem to work so far. I tried the following:

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, car_brand="BMW", **kwargs):
    
    
        car_brand = 'Mercedes'
    
        # change car_brand variable with exec
        exec("identifier " + "= 'Audi'")
    
        # change car_brand variabel with local
        str = "car_brand"
        locals()[str] = 'Audi'
    
        self.car_brand = car_brand
    
sc = SomeClass(car_brand="BMW")
sc.car_brand
```

My output is "Mercedes" so apparently it is possible to simply overwrite the input argument however it is not possible to overwrite the variable with "Audi" using the string "car_brand" as variable name.

Comment: This has been done to death. Just use a dictionary.

Comment: You shouldn't call a variable `str`, that's a built-in name. Also, what is `car_bran` in the line `self.car_brand = car_bran`? Also, `exec("identifier " + "= 'Audi'")` relevant at all to this post?

Comment: What I want to use it for is instantiating the class either with the argument car_brand="Audi" or with a kwargs dictionary kwargs={"car_brand":"Audi"}. Maybe there is a much better way to achieve this in general?

Comment: Check if the key `"car_brand"` was provided in the dictionary?

Comment: `self.car_brand = kwargs["car_brand"] if "car_brand" in kwargs else "Audi"` ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515070/how-to-update-dictionary-values-present-within-local-symbol-table

Comment: yes thats exactly what I do but I am trying to put it in a for-loop to automatically use all dict keys as variable names for the respective dict value

Comment: locals(), on the other hand, returns a dictionary that is a current copy of the local namespace, not a reference to it. So you can’t modify objects in the actual local namespace using the return value from locals().

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.

```py
# modifying the globals
globals()[name] = value
```

```py
from operator import setitem
setitem(globals(), name, value)
```

```py
# custom dicionary, like globals
custom_dict[name] = value
```

Perhaps you want to modify only the current instance's attributes?

```py
setattr(self, name, value)
```