# How can I automate the creation of Pandas dataframes, from a folder of .xls, with a list of variable names?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder with a number of files. I want to import the sheet 'sheet1' as a pandas dataframe for each of them, assigned to the name of a portion of that title.

I've successfully gotten a list of filenames:

```
path = "/Users/path"
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']
```

> ['A.xls', 'B.xls']

And I've successfully made a list of names I'd like as the dataframe names:

```
names = map(lambda each:each.strip(".xls"), files_xls)
```

> ['A', 'B']

But I'm failing at using these names to import. I can do it manually:

```
A = pd.read_excel(A.xls, 'sheet1')
B = pd.read_excel(B.xls, 'sheet1')
etc...
```

But I can't figure out how to automate this process.

Comment: I suggest you just use a dict to do this, define the keys as your string names and the values as the dfs

Answer (score 1):

Use `.zip` to combine your two `lists` into a `dict`, iterate over the result using `.items()` and collect `pd.read_excel()` in a `dict`:

```
df = {}
for name, f in dict(zip(names, files_xls)).items():
    df[name] = pd.read_excel(f, 'sheet1')
```

`df['A']` will then contain the result of `pd.read_excel('A.xls')`.

You could simplify creating the `list` of names using:

```
names = [f[:-4] for f in files_xls]
```

This works as follows:

```
files_xls = ['A.xls', 'B.xls']

names = [f[:-4] for f in files_xls]
['A', 'B']

name_dict = dict(zip(names, files_xls))
{'A': 'A.xls', 'B': 'B.xls'}

for name, f in name_dict.items():
    print(name, f)
```

prints:

```
A A.xls
B B.xls
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this is doing / where it isn't accomplishing what I'm hoping for, but the error I'm getting when I then just run 'B':

NameError: name 'B' is not defined

Comment: So the goal here is to have 'A' yield the dataframe created by A.xls

Comment: 'A' is the dictionary key. `df['A']` holds the `DataFrame`.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. Is there a way to make it so just 'A' holds the DataFrame? That's been my real goal.

Comment: Can't assign to `string` literals. Try `'A' = 3` in a python shell. Dictionaries are quite common practice for a case like this. There's the `exec` command though, take a look here down the thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop

Comment: Following the 'exec' path you recommended, I eventually came upon, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4357876/1318135, which is what I'm using successfully, together with your answer.

Comment: glad it was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

There are two options that suppose to work for you:

**1.**

```
for name in names:
    xlsx[name] = pd.ExcelFile('PATH\' + name + '.xlsx')
    sheets[name] = xlsx.parse(0)
```

**2.**

```
for name in names:    
    xlsx[name] = pd.read_excel(open('PATH\' + name + '.xlsx','rb'), sheetname='Sheet1')
```

Note that xlsx and sheets are dictionaries.

Comment: Trying to implement #2, I get: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: xlsx is a dictionary: 
xlsx = dict() and **not** xlsx = []